# Invalidate block cache after attribute was edited

Tags: attributes, cache, product-attribute, block-cache

How to invalidate block cache after product attribute was edited. E.g. there is a multiselect attribte and if I edit its values in Magento admin I need the cache of the block to be deleted and refreshed.

There are many examples of how to do this when specific product was edited, e.g. on Magento forum: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 120,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG . "_" . $this->getProduct()->getId()),
        'cache_key'         => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
    ));
}
```

but how to do this for attributes?

I've found the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::CACHE_TAG` constant for attributes but I'm not sure how to use it to delete the cache only when specific attribute was edited:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 120,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::CACHE_TAG),
        'cache_key'         => $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `'cache_key' => $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product)` you don't have to invalidate the cache, it will have different cache key when you edit the product.
It would be better to use a key like this one `'cache_key' => 'MY_BLOCK_PRODUCT_' . $product->getId() . '_COLOR_' $product->getColor()`.

Comment: Thank you. That cache_key was only an example copied from somewhere, in my case the key will be different. So I will need to use cache_tags to refresh the cache.